# How to Upload image with multiple parameter to servlet

Tags: java, image, servlets

I want to upload image and multiple fields using a HTML `form` with POST method and a `Servlet`. The data will be stored to database once received. I searched, but only found  solutions for uploading file only or fields.

Example :

- File : Image
- Field : Image ID
- Field : Image Name
- etc

How to create a `form` and `Servlet` to achieve that?

Comment: parameter is nothing but imageid,imagename

Comment: no i use java and servlet

Comment: are you aware of javascript form data objects?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 1):

you can create a formdata object and populate the same as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)
and retrive later as a request parameter like `String message = request.getParameter("message");`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a `multipart/form-data` HTML form to post your data to the servlet example :

```
<form action="file-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="field1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="file1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Note that you will have to change the `action` attribute in order to post to the right URL, pay attention to your application context!

Now the servlet part, there is many way of doing it but one easy is to use the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) library. You only need to add the JAR to your project.

Here is an example that will get your informations and print content in HTML :

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/file-upload" } )
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest p_oRequest, HttpServletResponse p_oResponse) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out = p_oResponse.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body>");

        List fileItems = null;

        // Parsing field values
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(10000000);

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        // maximum file size to be uploaded.
        upload.setSizeMax(10000000);

        try
        {
            // Parse the request to get file items.
            fileItems = upload.parseRequest(p_oRequest);

            // Process the uploaded file items
            Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

            out.println("<table><tr><td>Type</td><td>Name</td><td>Value</td>");

            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();

                out.println("<tr>");

                if(fi.isFormField())
                {
                    out.println("<td>Field</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + fi.getFieldName() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + fi.getString() + "</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    out.println("<td>File</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + fi.getFieldName() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + fi.getName() + " / " + fi.getContentType() + " / " + fi.getSize() + "</td>");
                }

                out.println("</tr>");
            }

            out.println("</table>");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Note the `FileItem fi` is the object that contains field information. For the file, you can get its content with `fi.getInputStream()` or `fi.getString()` depending on how you want to get it and how much data, etc.

Comment: but i want upload image and field from java

Comment: @KarthikKeyan Image is a file (`input type="file"`) and fields are text (`input type="text"`).